# How to add/modify HTML attributes through Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a button in html, let's say:

```
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

I wish to be able to disable this button through flask (for example after it has been pushed). What I would like to know is how I would add the *disabled* attribute onto the button. In other words, turning it into:

```
<button type="button" disabled>Button</button>
```

Comment: After the template has been rendered? You would need javascript for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `return render_template('template.html', variables=values)` at the end of your route, pass a boolean:

```
return render_template('template.html', var1=val1, var2=val2,..., button=button)
```

You can set the value of `button` in your route. Then in your jinja2 template, just put in a branch:

```
{% if button %}
<button type="button">Button</button>
{% else %}
<button type="button" disabled>Button</button>
{% endif %}
```

If you need the button to be disabled dynamically after the page is rendered, @ltd9938 is correct, you need javascript.

I read now you mean after it has been pushed, in which case, yes, you need javascript.